# How not to remove items from a list, which is being indexed to remove items from another list?

Tags: python-3.x, list, sequence

I'm trying to remove some items from a list, and the required indexes are in another list.

I've tried list.pop(), but it also removes items from the parent list, just like list.remove()

```
sequence = [3, 6, 5, 8, 10, 20, 15]
sortS = sorted(sequence)
seq = sequence
for i in range(len(sequence)):
    seq.remove(sequence[i])
    sortS.remove(sequence[i])


print(sequence)
>>>[]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to clone or copy a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.copy()` when you assign 1 list element to other. In Python it simply references to that variable and if any changes is made to that variable will be made to referenced one too.

With using `.copy()` new memory space will be created and any change to this won't affect the original

```
sequence = [3, 6, 5, 8, 10, 20, 15]
sortS = sorted(sequence)
seq = sequence.copy()
for i in range(len(sequence)):
    seq.remove(sequence[i])
    sortS.remove(sequence[i])


print(sequence)
```

output

```
[3, 6, 5, 8, 10, 20, 15]
```